# Which bond corresponds to which curve?

Tags: bond, yield-curve

- Bond X has a coupon
- Bond Y is a zero-coupon bond (Maturity 2 years)
- Bond Z is a zero-coupon bond (Maturity 10 years)

The following graph is given:

[image: bondXYZ]

X-axis: yield curve, Y-axis: price

**Question**: *Which bond corresponds to which curve?*

What is the way to solve a question like this? A little help is appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a homework to me.

Comment: Ask yourself: if everything is the same, do you prefer a zero-coupon bond with 2 years or 10 years? The bond that you prefer will also be more expensive because everybody wants it too. What's the relationship with the yields?

Comment: The holder of a zero-coupon bond receives only at the end date a payment. A 2 years would be more preferable.

Comment: What has that to do with the yields? Once you know it, read again the shape of yield-curve for a zero-coupon-bond in a text book, you should know the answer.

Comment: Bond prices and interest rates move in opposite direction. For a high value of the yield, the 2 year bond would be more expensive than the 10 year bond.

Comment: So Y = A and Z = B. What remains X = C.